# Splitting examples in Given and Then for SpecFlow Scenario Outline

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I am writing a specflow scenario with multiple input and output parameters (about 4-5 each). When using scenario outline, I need to write a wide table giving both input and output columns in the same row. Is there any way where I can specify the examples separately for the step definitions? This is for improved readability.

**Current state**

```
Given - State of the data
When I trigger action with parameters <input1> and <input2> and ...
Then my output should contain <output1> and <output2> ...

Examples:
| input1 | input2 |... | output1 | output2 |...
```

**Can I do this?**

```
Given - State of the data
When I trigger action with parameters <input1> and <input2> and ...
       Examples of input
Then my output should contain <output1> and <output2> ...
        Examples of output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately that (or anything similar) is not possible.
You could make your inputs and outputs more abstract and possibly merge a few columns. Example: instead of Country | PostalCode | City | Street | House | Firstname | Lastname | etc. you should have | Address | Job title | with values like "EU", "US, missing postal code", "HQ" for the address.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have to live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple Example tables for scenario outline but you can pass in data tables for regular scenarios.

The data table will be accessible only to the step that uses it, however you could save it in Scenario Context for subsequent steps.

Not sure if this will work for you if your scenario is complex and spans multiple lines but I thought I'd mention it.

```
Scenario: Checking outputs for inputs
Given - State of the data
When I trigger action with the following parameters  
input1 | input2 | input3 |
data   | data   | data   |

Then my output should contain the following outputs
output1 | output2  | output3 |
data    | data     | data    |
```

Comment: No. I thought of that but my inputs are complex and cannot be put as columns like you mentioned.